Does $\text{Var}((AWy)^TAWy) \geq \text{Var}((AW_1y)^TAW_1y)$?
Suppose $W$ is an $n\times n$ random matrix with each entry i.i.d. $\sim N(0,1)$, let $A = (WDW^T +\lambda I_n)^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with every entry $>0$, $I_n$ the idendity matrix of dimention $n$, $\lambda>0$.
Does $\text{Var}((AWy)^TAWy) \geq \text{Var}((AW_1y)^TAW_1y)$ where $W_1$ is i.i.d. to $W$ and any $ y\in \mathbb{R^n}$?
It seems intuitive because $(AW)^TAW$ involves something like $\sum w_iw_jw_kw_l$ where $w_\sim N(0,1)$, and on the left hand side we have more $\sum w_i^2w_j^2$ terms instead of $\sum w_iw_jw_kw_l$ which should make its variance bigger? If this is true, how to prove it?

It is unclear what $W_1$ is here? Is it random, or a fixed nonrandom matrix? For example, if $W_1$ is a matrix of zeros, then the result is false.

@Daan $W_1$ is i.i.d. to $W$. BTW, if $W_1$ is zeros, shouldn't it be always true since variance is always positive?

The variance of a random variable is not always positive. Take for example the random variable $X$ satisfying $X(\omega)=c$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$, then $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}X)^2=\int_\Omega (X(\omega)-c)^2\mathrm{d}P=0$. However, it is easy to show that it is nonnegative, as $\mathbb{E}|X-\mathbb{E}X|^2=\mathbb{E}X^2-(\mathbb{E}X)^2\geq(\mathbb{E}X)^2-(\mathbb{E}X)^2=0$ by Jensen's inequality.
